# Need help refactoring a MongoDB query in C#. Can I "convert" a BsonDocument to IMongoQuery?

Tags: c#, mongodb, search

disclaimer: I am a total noob so please be gentle.

I am trying to refactor a method that returns an IMongoQuery object with a query that is not very efficient. I have pasted the queries below (original and desired). I've tried various ways of constructing the query but with my limited knowledge, the best way I know how to do it is to create it up manually as a BsonDocument; but then I don't know how to turn that into an IMongoQuery.

Can anyone give me some pointers on the best way I should go about it?

**Original Query**

```
{
    "$or": [{
            "$and": [{
                    "$or": [{
                            "identifier": {
                                "$elemMatch": {
                                    "code": "CustomerName1",
                                    "system": "NameSystem"
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "identifier.0": {
                                "$exists": false
                            },
                            "identifier.code": "CustomerName1",
                            "identifier.system": "NameSystem"
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "$or": [{
                            "identifier": {
                                "$elemMatch": {
                                    "code": "CustomerCode1",
                                    "system": "CodeSystem"
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "identifier.0": {
                                "$exists": false
                            },
                            "identifier.code": "CustomerCode1",
                            "identifier.system": "CodeSystem"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "$and": [{
                    "$or": [{
                            "identifier": {
                                "$elemMatch": {
                                    "code": "CustomerName2",
                                    "system": "NameSystem"
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "identifier.0": {
                                "$exists": false
                            },
                            "identifier.code": "CustomerName2",
                            "identifier.system": "NameSystem"
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "$or": [{
                            "identifier": {
                                "$elemMatch": {
                                    "code": "CustomerCode2",
                                    "system": "CodeSystem"
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "identifier.0": {
                                "$exists": false
                            },
                            "identifier.code": "CustomerCode2",
                            "identifier.system": "CodeSystem"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Desired Query**

```
{
    "$or": [{
            "$and": [{
                    "$or": [{
                            "identifier": {
                                "$elemMatch": {
                                    "code": {
                                        "$in": ["CustomerName1", "CustomerName2"]
                                    },
                                    "system": "NameSystem"
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "identifier.0": {
                                "$exists": false
                            },
                            "identifier.code": {
                                "$in": ["CustomerName1", "CustomerName2"]
                            },
                            "identifier.system": "NameSystem"
                        }
                    ]
                }, {
                    "$or": [{
                            "identifier": {
                                "$elemMatch": {
                                    "code": {
                                        "$in": ["CustomerCode1", "CustomerCode2"]
                                    },
                                    "system": "CodeSystem"
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            "identifier.0": {
                                "$exists": false
                            },
                            "identifier.code": {
                                "$in": ["CustomerCode1", "CustomerCode2"]
                            },
                            "identifier.system": "CodeSystem"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't know what an `IMongoQuery` is (I've never used that aspect of Mongo) but you can use a `BsonDocument` in place of a `FilterDefinition<T>`: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinition_1_op_Implicit.htm

Answer (score 0):

OK nevermind, I ended up building it up with a lot of MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Query :)

It works, but if anyone wants to share a more elegant solution, I am all ears.

```cs
        var queryList = new List<IMongoQuery>();
        queryList.Add(M.Query.In("code", restrictionList));
        queryList.Add(M.Query.EQ("system", system));
        var query1 = M.Query.ElemMatch("identifier", M.Query.And(queryList));

        queryList.Clear();
        queryList.Add(M.Query.In("identifer.code", restrictionList));
        queryList.Add(M.Query.EQ("identifer.system", system));
        queryList.Add(M.Query.NotExists("identifer.0"));
        var query2 = M.Query.And(queryList);

        queryList.Clear();
        queryList.Add(query1);
        queryList.Add(query2);

        var restrictionQuery = M.Query.Or(queryList);
        return restrictionQuery;
```